# CMake+Xcode: Archive fails for an app depending on a library in the same solution. Make Archive build in the BUILD_TREE instead of Xcode/DerivedData?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode6, cmake

We ported our codebase to use CMake for build management some weeks ago. We realize now that there is a major problem when we are trying to **Archive** an application that depends on one (or several) library built in the same Xcode solution.

The linker fails because it cannot find the depended upon library (and the library is indeed not present where it is looking for it).

### minimal example

Here is a minimal example producing the issue:

In CMakeLists.txt

```
##
## The library
##
project(library)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    utils.h
    utils.cpp
)


##
## The application
##
project(CocoaApp)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_XIB
    MainMenu.xib
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE
    AppDelegate.h
    AppDelegate.mm
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_XIB}
    main.mm
)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} library "-framework Cocoa")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
                      RESOURCE "${${PROJECT_NAME}_XIB}")
```

When generating an Xcode project from this simple CMake scripts, if trying to call **Archive** command, the compilation phase itself goes fine, but the linker phase fails with this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '<path_to_build_tree>/Release/libLibrary.a'
```

And there is indeed no libLibrary.a to be found in ${build_tree}/Release/. (If the library target was first compiled in Release, the file would already be there, but it is not viable as **Archive** should be self contained.)

Is this a bug ? Is there a workaround ?

### Edit: setting ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY on the lib

If `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is set for the **Library** target, then a file is indeed created in CMake's build_tree. Actually setting its value to "./" even places it where a 'normal' Release build would place the library.

The problem here is that the file that is placed in the build_tree is merely a soft link to the actual library (in  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../.../libLibrary.a). Instead, we would need that the "Archive" action builds the actual file here, exactly like a Release build would (or at least move it there when its done).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318941/cmake-generated-xcode-project-release-build-works-but-archive-fails-on-linker) looks very similar. Have you tried its answer?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for the link. I tried it (by using **CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY** instead, since it initializes `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`on all subsequent targets). What is strange is that setting it to "./" is enough to make the files appear in the right directory. The problem is that the files are only symlinks to some internal Xcode storage (i.e., the *DerivedData* folder), whereas we would need the actual file to be built in CMake's build_tree directly.